# Declaring a date as UTC in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I receive a date/time value from my backend API as a string in the following format `"2020-08-04T14:30"` and this value is a UTC date/time.

When I convert this to `Date` in JavaScript -- see below --  it's showing me my time zone. Is there a way to declare a date/time value **as UTC**?

```
const myValue = "2020-08-04T14:30";
const myDate = new Date(myValue); // This date object is showing my time zone and NOT UTC
```

Along with the date/time value, my API also gives me a `utcOffset` value. I'm trying to create a simple util function that will give me a date object by applying the `utcOffset` value.

```
export const convertFromUtc = (date, utcOffset) => {
   const utcDate = new Date(date);
   let localDate = utcDate;
   return localDate.setMinute(utcDate.getMinute() - utcOffset);
};
```

This code is working fine but when I inspect the `utcDate` object, it's showing me my local time zone. I think it should indicate the time zone as UTC. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `const myValue = "2020-08-04T14:30Z"`

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Would I do `new Date.UTC(myDateStringFromApi)`?

Comment: `Date` objects don't have a timezone associated with them in javascript. i would consider using something like moment to help you

Comment: @DanielA.White If that's the case, I can just ignore the time zone. As I mentioned in the original post, my util function works fine. It just bothered me that it was showing my time zone for the `utcDate` variable.

Comment: thats just a display concern. "A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, UTC."

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Comment: @DanielA.White Got it! Thank you!